# How to disable GPU

Tags: linux, gpu

is it possible to disable GPU ? Let's say you have one PC (keyboard,mouse and monitor are connected) and you can see everything on your monitor. If you remove keyboard and mouse AND you don't need monitor,you would remove everything from PC, but STILL GPU works (does it ?)

I ask this because I think there is power consumption that I don't need (it's waste), so is it possible to do something like this ?

If it is relevant, I use Linux.

Comment: Try `rmmod`-ing the relevant kernel modules.

Comment: I will take a look about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need a GPU use onboard. Power consumption is very low especially on newer boards that have graphics processing built into the CPU (such as the Intel HD series).

And to answer your question, no. It's a necessary device.

Comment: Do you mean like CPU and RAM are not sufficient for "normal" operating ?

Comment: I mean, there's no real reason to *not* have GPU support. You never know when you need a console session at some point if something bad happens (and it will, nature of technology).

Comment: Maybe I wont to turn off GPU while there is nothing in USB ports, and turn it back on when something is plugged in. Let USB be trigger for.

Comment: As far as I know, this isn't possible. Especially with onboard hardware, you're powering the device even if it's not enabled in the OS itself.